# Check null values in Linq query in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, null

How can I compare integer type null values Where portion of Linq query in .Net Entity framework 4.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only compare an `int` to `NULL` if the `int` is `nullable`. If not, the default value for `int` will be `0` and never `null`.

You define a nullable int property like this:

```
int? value { get; set; }
```

And check it like this:

```
if ( value != null )
{
   int x = value.Value;
}
```

In the where clause of a Linq query it would be

```
var result = from d in data
             where d.Value != null
             select d
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are comparing to a `null` value, you must first compare your value to `null` due to a bug.

```
var field = from field in table
            where (value == null ? field.property == null : field.property == value)
            select field;
```

Comment: @Eric http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title